# Coroutines on a single thread and guaranteed sequentiality

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Given the following program is '1' guaranteed to print before '2'?

```
private val dispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val job1 = testLaunch(1)
        val job2 = testLaunch(2)

        job1.join()
        job2.join()
        dispatcher.close()
    }
}

private fun testLaunch(num: Int): Job =
    GlobalScope.launch(dispatcher) {
        println(num)
    }
```

What about this one?

```
private val mainDispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
private val asyncDispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val job1 = testLaunch(1)
        val job2 = testLaunch(2)

        job1.join()
        job2.join()
        mainDispatcher.close()
        asyncDispatcher.close()
    }
}

private fun testLaunch(num: Int): Job =
    GlobalScope.launch(mainDispatcher) {
        val task = GlobalScope.async(asyncDispatcher) {
            ;
        }
        task.await()
        println(num)
    }
```

Comment: There is no guarantee for the ordering of concurrent coroutines. Whether the dispatcher is single-threaded or not doesn't even enter that equation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Do you have some sources confirming that statement? Pls

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If we want to launch sequential coroutines and make sure the first actually gets launched before the second, is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, there is no way to get such a guarantee. It's just like with threads, if you want to coordinate between coroutines, you must use synchronization tools. However, why would you even base the correctness of your program on something like that? Don't use concurrent coroutines for sequential execution.

Comment: @aiqency You should ask for a source that confirms the existence a guarantee, not the lack of one. In this case, the very word "concurrent" says it all.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I've got you. It's the same as for thread after all. Thanks

Comment: What you _could_ do is use the deprecated parameter to launch: `launch(start = UNDISPATCHED)`. The coroutine will start executing right away, without dispatching it to a given thread. If you do this within the `runBlocking` code which is already on the single thread in charge, it will work. But it's clearly a hacky approach.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this answer says the opposite of what you are saying: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765485/does-executors-newsinglethreadexecutor-always-excute-tasks-in-order-they-were

Comment: @DiegoMarin but that is a naked single threaded executor, who knows if the coroutine code will actually submit them in order to the underlying executor.

Comment: A potential bug was reported about it also https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8034938

Comment: @DiegoMarin I don't see the relevance. First of all, you linked to a Java question about executors, Kotlin coroutine dispatchers don't inherit their contracts. Second, even the executor in question just states the obvious fact that a single thread guarantees sequential execution of tasks. It does not say anything about the ordering of the tasks. That is an inappropriate conclusion of the author on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you are right. Even if we check the code and come to the conclusion that coroutines will be executed in order, if it is not explicitly stated in the documentation of the method, you shouldn't assume this behavioir as it is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

### It is not guaranteed to execute sequentially.

Coroutines will give up the thread if a suspending function such as delay is called. i.e. Making this adjustment

```kotlin
    private val dispatcher: ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()

    fun main(args: Array<out String>) =
      runBlocking {
      val job1 = testLaunch(num = 1, delayTime = 2000L)
      val job2 = testLaunch(num = 2, delayTime = 500L)

      job1.join()
      job2.join()
      dispatcher.close()

    }

    private fun testLaunch(num: Int, delayTime: Long): Job = GlobalScope.launch(dispatcher) {
      println("Executing job $num and waiting $delayTime millis")
      delay(delayTime)
      println(num)
    }
```

You will see the following output:

```sh
Executing job 1 and waiting 2000 millis
Executing job 2 and waiting 500 millis
2
1
```

In the above case job 2 begins and exits before job 1 exits.

### Since [Flows are sequential](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html#flows-are-sequential) you might want to try something like this.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<out String>) = runBlocking {
  val jobFlow = flowOf(1 to 5000L, 2 to 500L)
    .map { (num, delayTime) -> testLaunch(num, delayTime) }
    .map { job -> job.join() }
    .onCompletion { dispatcher.close() }
    .collect { println("Job complete") }

}

private fun testLaunch(num: Int, delayTime: Long): Job = GlobalScope.launch(dispatcher) {
  println("Executing job $num I don't care how long I have to wait. I'm holding onto this thread until I'm done.")
  delay(delayTime)
  println("Okay... I'm done executing job $num")
}
```

Which will yield the output

```sh
Executing job 1 I don't care how long I have to wait. I'm holding onto this thread until I'm don/
Okay... I'm done executing job 1
Job complete
Executing job 2 I don't care how long I have to wait. I'm holding onto this thread until I'm don/
Okay... I'm done executing job 2
Job complete
```

#### Although I would personally decide to forgo the use of the dispatcher, global scope, and jobs.

Implementing something like this instead

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<out String>) = runBlocking {
  val jobFlow = flowOf(1, 2)
    .map { num -> suspendPrint(num) }
    .onCompletion { println("All jobs complete") }
    .collect { println("Job complete") }
}

private suspend  fun suspendPrint(num: Int) {
  println(num)
}
```

Comment: I understand that coroutines will give up the thread if a suspending function is called, but that's not what I'm asking, there were no suspending functions in the first example.

Comment: I'm addressing the guaranteed sequential execution of corroutines on a single thread in a more general case. Providing a scenario in which execution is not sequential to illustrate how the pattern in your first example cannot be relied on. Are Flows not suitable for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to do that, and this is because coroutines are developed to chunk down the asynchronous way of writing code and make it easy it has nothing to do with the execution order.

A simple example of those feature could work in your case:

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val job1 = sequentialWork(1)
    val job2 = sequentialWork(2, after=job1)

    ... //cleanups
}

private fun sequentialWork(num: Int, after: Job? = null): Job = dispatcher.launch{
    if(after==null) {
        println("I'm $num executing")
    } else {
        after.join()
        println("I'm $num executing")
    }
}
```

Since the join() is a suspending function and inside the launch block hence it will not affect or suspend the main, but instead will ensure to suspend until `after: Job` has been completed.

However there is also an option of by passing the [CoroutineStart.LAZY](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-start/index.html) into start parameter of [launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) function